# Find deprecated or changed methods in site core with different versions

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore8

I am planning to migrate site core 6.5 to site core 8.1. So here i am using below dlls sample

1. Sitecore.nexus
2. Sitecore.NVelocity
3. Sitecore.Analytics
4. Sitecore.Marketing.Wildcards and etc.

While i am doing POC i got understand **Sitecore.Marketing.Wildcards** is changed because of vast changes in Rules Engine.I figured out by compile time errors in my code after code has setup with sitecore 8.1. So i planned for another work around.

My question is how can I find a way to discover deprecated or changed functions from one version to another version of site core migrations? I'm trying to fgire this out before I dive into development.

Comment: Each version of sitecore comes with [release notes](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/Sitecore%2081/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2081%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes) that should document all these breaking changes. You could possibly write your own patches to port the old functionality to new. Not sure how feasible or difficult this would be as it'd depend on each individual change. TBH I think your going to have to re-write any broken functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to go through the release notes and find what is changed.

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/Sitecore%2081/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2081%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes

For example, on the release notes for Sitecore 8.1 on above link, you will find certain deprecated features, functionality, framework like SPEAK 1.1 framework etc. So with every release, some features or components may get deprecated and you need to fix the code break due to this.